# Overheating 2005 Pt Crusier

Tags: coolant-reservoir, pt-cruiser

my 2005 PT Crusier coolant over flow container isn't holding any coolant  at all. I put water to the marked amount of  50/50 and it doesn't hold any of it. Over heating problems because of it. I lost the cap to it sometime ago. I put a temporary homemade one on it, but only since I lost the original one. Help! I need to fix it.

Comment: Can you take a picture of your engine compartment and post it somewhere?  Edit your question to include a link.  There are two different types of overflow control systems on modern cars.  One is pure overflow with simple dust cap (e.g. Toyota) the other is an in system reservoir with high pressure radiator style cap (e.g. Ford).  Oh, and I suspect you have a hose leak somewhere.

Comment: Are you witnessing puddles of coolant under your car? As zipzit mentioned, these cooling systems are typically closed. If you are missing or have a defective cap which is used to seal the system, you will lose coolant and it will overheat. Also, continuous loss of coolant can allow air into the system which can make it difficult to get out. Please tell us more about what cap you are missing and what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Check for leaks in the radiator, hoses or water pump when engine hot and running. Also check oil dipstick to make sure oil has not turned milky due to a blown head gasket. Do not drive the car without water, you will damage it.

The bottle is a top up container for the radiator, when the fluid gets hot it expands and pushes into the bottle, when it cools it contracts and sucks the fluid back into the motor.

Make sure the radiator is always full of fluid, do not remove the radiator cap when the engine is hot or you will get injured with hot water.